# How to properly get code logs from container in host using docker compose and volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to understand how to share logs generated by a toy project into a volume. The logs are generated inside a docker container.

For this, I am using docker-compose version 3.
So far, I built the volume and the container with docker compose. However,  when I check the volume I don't find any files coming from the container.
Here is the project architecture:

[image]

Here is what is inside the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:


    #Chatbot Service
    test_bot:
        build: ./test_bot
        image: test_bot:1.0
        #restart: always
        expose:
            - "5000"
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        volumes:
            - test_volume:/app/test_bot
#            volume:
#              nocopy: true

volumes:
    test_volume:

networks:
    negusnet:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.192.10.0/16

    negus.jitsi:
```

Here is what is inside the dockerfile.yml:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

#Enviroment variables creation
ENV TEST_HOME=/app/test_bot

# Run updates, install basics and cleanup
# - build-essential: Compile specific dependencies
# - git-core: Checkout git repos
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential git-core openssl libssl-dev libffi6 libffi-dev curl nano git wget\
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# use bash always
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

#Define the path of home repository
WORKDIR ${TEST_HOME}


#Copy all files in existing negus_ai repository in docker
COPY . ${TEST_HOME}


RUN python3 ${TEST_HOME}/run_script.py
```

And finally, here is my test_script:

```
import logging
import time


logging.basicConfig(filename='Client_logs.log',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i=0
    while(True):
        i=i+1

        logging.info("yay is is "+str(i))
        time.sleep(30)
```

[EDIT1]
Just to be clear, I don't want any manipulation involving getting inside the container or having to copy manually the logs from it to the host machine.

[EDIT2] I check the container using docker container inspect id. No volumes seems to be linked to it. The mount parameter is empty.

Comment: Look inside the container, and `find` where the log actually was written?

Comment: and copy it to the host?

Comment: Probably not. First, you need to figure out what the problem is. Then you can devise a solution.

Comment: The log is where it should be in the container. It is called Client_logs.log

Comment: What is "where it should be in the container"? That isn't a path.

Comment: in /app/test_bot

Comment: Did the volume you specified actually get mounted to the container? Try `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <containerid>` and look for it.

Comment: No . It is not. I made an edit related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem was a bit tricky.
All I had to do was replace

```
RUN python3 ${TEST_HOME}/run_script.py
```

with :

```
ENTRYPOINT python3 ${TEST_HOME}/run_script.py
```

Apparently, the volume binding to the container is not made if we use the line with RUN.